# Why is the set of diagonal matrices not an ideal?

Tags: linear-algebra, ideals

Saw this fact in my lecture notes, but can't quite seem to work out why this is the case. Its clearly a subgroup of $M_n(\Re)$ and it seems that when multiplied by any element of $M_n(\Re)$ a diagonal matrix will result in a diagonal matrix. Definitely missing something insanely simple and trivial here but cant quite work it out.

Comment: Why does it seem that the product of a diagonal matrix and any other matrix is diagonal? Have you tried some specific cases?

Comment: No, if you multiply a (nonzero) diagonal matrix by a non-diagonal matrix, you almost never get a diagonal matrix: left-multiplying by a diagonal matrix is equivalent to multiplying each row by a number (the corresponding diagonal entry), multiplying on the right is equivalent to multiplying each column by a number.

Answer (score 7):

What you're missing is that the product of a diagonal matrix with an arbitrary matrix is *almost never* a diagonal matrix. For instance, suppose that your diagonal matrix is the identity matrix and that the other matrix is *any* non-diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you  `left`-multiply an $n\times n$ matrix  by the diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(a_1, a_2,\dots,a_n)$, for each $i=1,\dots, n$, you multiply  *row* $i$ of the matrix by $a_i$, and when you `right`-mutiply it by $D$, it's *column* $i$ you multiply  by $a_i$.